# How can I make a Condition in TypoScript for loading different JavaScript-Files to different Backend-Layouts? (TYPO3)

Tags: typo3, conditional-statements, typoscript, typo3-8.x

After a "long way" with Google, Searching and many tries:

I created a lib.variable for the current Page:

```
lib.currentPage = TEXT
lib.currentPage.data = page:uid
```

If I debug it in my FluidTemplate in the Frontend with:

```
Testing currentPage: <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.currentPage" />
```

I got the correct value.

---

Now I want to use that Variable in a Condition in my `pageSetup.ts` like follows:

```
[DB:pages:lib.currentPage:backend_layout = pagets__pagelayout_logoclaim_subpage]
    page.includeJSFooter.belayoutlogoclaim = EXT:rm_base/Resources/Public/JS/be_logoclaim.js
[end]
```

I testet this with some other Conditions, but nothing works like expected.

Tested Conditions:

- [page|backend_layout = pagelayout_logoclaim_subpage]
- [globalVar = TSFE:page|backend_layout = pagelayout_logoclaim_subpage]

I also tested the Condition in the **TypoScript Object Browser**, and here it looks like good working:

TypoScript Object Browser - If I activate the Condition

[image: TypoScript Object Browser]

SourceCode in the Frontend on a Site with the correct PageLayout

[image: SourceCode with the correct PageLayout]

I need this, because I have two different Menus, and they need different JavaScripts, to avoid wrong behaviour in the Frontend.

---

**Update**:
I inserted the pageLayouts like this:

```
page = PAGE
page {

    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        partialRootPath = EXT:rm_base/Resources/Private/Templates/Fluid/Partials/
        layoutRootPath = EXT:rm_base/Resources/Private/Templates/Fluid/Layouts/

        file.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
        file.stdWrap.cObject {
            key.data = pagelayout

            // Default-Template is LogoFull_Subpage (No Navigation Dependence)
            default = TEXT
            default.value = EXT:rm_base/Resources/Private/Templates/Fluid/LogoFull_Subpage.html

            // LogoClaim - Subpage
            pagets__pagelayout_logoclaim_subpage = TEXT
            pagets__pagelayout_logoclaim_subpage.value = EXT:rm_base/Resources/Private/Templates/Fluid/LogoClaim_Subpage.html
        }
    }
```

You see: The **Backendlayouts are in Files of my Extension**, not in the Database-Table: backend_layouts.

**Update 2**:

I would prefer a TypoScript-Way, if someone knows how - with external BE-Layouts. Thank you.

Comment: Did you connect your backend layout with a frontend Fluid template each?

Comment: As I've seen the prefix `pagets__` I guess that the problem here is that the backend_layouts are not stored in the database.
If there is a different html template file for each backend layout, one solution could be the usage of the section `<f:section name="FooterAssets">` (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.6/Feature-79409-AutorenderAssetSectionsInFluidTemplateWithController.html)

Comment: @MathiasBrodala I updated my question ... I have all BE-Layouts in the same CASE object. @ RiccardoDeContardi I have the BE-Layouts inside a file yes - not in the Database. I don't understand the Content of your Link, but I try to learn and find out ;). Thanks

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi .. Now I understand that way you show me... thanks.. if you want to write an answer, I can upvote and accept it. | but if you know a typoscript solution, it would be better and cleaner... Isn't it bad code-smell if we put fluid and javascript-calls in the same file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution, that uses a TypoScript Custom Condition:

First I create a BackendlayoutCondition.php in my Extension here:

```
/Classes/TypoScript/BackendlayoutCondition.php
```

Its content is this (See Comments for more Detail):

```
<?php
namespace RM\RmBase\TypoScript;

use \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Configuration\TypoScript\ConditionMatching\AbstractCondition;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;;

class BackendlayoutCondition extends AbstractCondition
{
    /**
     * Evaluate condition
     *
     * @param array $conditionParameters
     * @return bool
     */
    public function matchCondition(array $conditionParameters)
    {
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($conditionParameters,'cond Params');

        # Return false if in Backend (Condition for Frontend only)
        if (!$GLOBALS['TSFE']) return false;

        # QueryBuilder for Table: pages
        $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('pages');

        # Check if current BackendLayout is inside the $conditionParameters
        if (!empty($conditionParameters) && substr($conditionParameters[0], 0, 1) === '=') {
            # Trim the Parameter to get the correct Value of the Parameter (behind '=')
            $conditionParameters[0] = trim(substr($conditionParameters[0], 1));

                # Get Backendlayout on this Page
                $backendLayoutOnThisPage = $queryBuilder
                    ->select('backend_layout')
                    ->from('pages')
                    ->where(
                        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('uid', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter(intval($GLOBALS['TSFE']->id), \PDO::PARAM_INT))
                    )
                    ->execute();

            # Store Backendlayout Value of the current Page in $backendLayoutOnThisPage
            $backendLayoutOnThisPage = $backendLayoutOnThisPage->fetch()['backend_layout'];
        } else {
            # If no ConditionParameter was set return false
            return false;
        }

        # Check if parent BackendLayout_NextLevel is inside the $conditionParameters
        if ($backendLayoutOnThisPage == '') {
            # Get pageRepository
            $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
            $pageRepository = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Page\\PageRepository');

            # Get Rootline of the current Page
            $pageRootline = $pageRepository->getRootLine(intval($GLOBALS['TSFE']->id));

            # Set rootlineIndex to the Parent Page Index
            $rootlineIndex = count($pageRootline)-2;

            # Check Parent Page Backendlayout_NextLevel till 0 or Backendlayout found
            while ($rootlineIndex > 0) {
                if ($pageRootline[$rootlineIndex]['backend_layout_next_level'] == $conditionParameters[0]) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    $rootlineIndex--;
                }
            }

            # No BackendLayout_NextLevel found till 0
            return false;
        } else {
            # If Condition Backendlayout found return true, otherwise return false
            if ($backendLayoutOnThisPage == $conditionParameters[0]) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(**Edited 2**)

Than I just have to use the following Condition in my `pageSetup.ts`:

```
[RM\RmBase\TypoScript\BackendlayoutCondition = pagelayout_logoclaim_subpage]
    page.includeJSFooter.belayoutlogoclaim = EXT:rm_base/Resources/Public/JS/be_logoclaim.js
[global]
```

Now I have this Sourcecode in the Frontend:

```
<script src="/typo3conf/ext/rm_base/Resources/Public/JS/be_logoclaim.js?1523005944" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

not that:

```
<script src="/typo3conf/ext/rm_base/Resources/Public/JS/be_logoclaim.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

if I use the FooterAssets method:

```
<f:section name="FooterAssets">
    <script src="/typo3conf/ext/rm_base/Resources/Public/JS/be_logoclaim.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</f:section>
```

---

**Edit**: I found some errors in my Answer, i fix it and edit my answer then.

**Edit2**: Now the Condition checks the Backendlayouts and the Backendlayouts_Nextlevel Fields for Backendlayouts to get all possible BE-Layouts including the inherited.

Comment: For newer TYPO3 versions (9.5 +) the procedure is a bit different, it's described here and the example with `[variableA  = "valueB"]` is also working: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/SymfonyExpressionLanguage/Index.html

Answer (score 2):

As I've seen the prefix  `pagets__` ,I guess that the problem here is that the backend_layouts are not stored in the database, so I think that a condition about that would not work.

If you are using a different html template for each backend layout and you are running TYPO3 8.7.x [there is a different way to solve this issue](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.6/Feature-79413-AutorenderAssetSectionsInFluidTemplateContentObject.html): Add to your template file a new section called:

```
<f:section name="FooterAssets">
<!--your code here-->
</f:section>
```

This section will be loaded just before the closing of `</body>`. As far as I remember you don't even have to call this section in your layout file.

Comment: Yes, I tried to call it, and got its content twice ;). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i would opt for using the VHS extension which provides an asset viewhelper.

you than include the asset view helper into the frontend template you are rendering. and it takes care about plaching the javascript in the header / footer
it allows also to definde dependancies and loads the script in the correct order. also supports concatination / minification ...

an example include might look like this:

```
<v:asset.script path="EXT:your_ext/Resources/Public/JavaScript/menu_a.js" dependencies="jquery" />
```

this requires you that you specified "jquery" via typoscript (or another assit view helper)

example typoscript:

```
plugin.tx_vhs.settings.asset.jquery {
  path = EXT:your_ext/Resources/Public/JavaScript/jquery.js
  type = js
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to use Third-Party-Extensions for this.

Comment: okay, unstand your point. you might still include your javascript plain into frontend template with a <script> tag.

Comment: it's a little bit dirty, but if it's the only way, yes I will do it that way... If someone knows a TypoScript Condition Option that works, with BE-Layouts in files, i prefer to use that solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `backend_layout` field is that there also is a field `backend_layout_next_level` which affects subpages. so you can't build a simple condition.

Either you use `stdWrap.if` where you can calculate the current value for `backend_layout` overlaying an inherited value from `backend_layout_next_level`.
Or you define a userfunc where you evaluate it yourself in PHP.

Be aware that layouts defined in records have another prefix than layouts defined in pagesTS.

---

edit: 
**Example**

```
temp.layout = CASE
temp.layout {
    key.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
    key.override.field = backend_layout

    default = TEXT
    default.value = default-layout

    1 = TEXT
    1.value = layoutdefinition_from_record

    pagets__layout2 = TEXT
    pagets__layout2.value = layoutdefinition_from_pageTSconfig

    sitepackage__layout3 = TEXT
    sitepackage__layout3.value = layoutdefinition_from_sitepackage
```

}

Now you can use `temp.layout` for further decisions:

```
10 = TEXT
10.field = bodytext
10.wrap = <div class="demo">|</div>
10.wrap.if {
    equals.cObject < temp.layout
    value = default-layout
}
```

Comment: How to use this for my issue, with the stdWrap.if Variation ? (Inlcuding BE-Layouts and BE-Nextlevel-Layouts)

Comment: I added a typoscript example.