# Why does an OR-Condition load double, when a Single-Condition load once in TypoScript Condition?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I created a custom TYPO3-Condition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49690175/7209206).

If I use the Condition this way:

```
## Custom JavaScript Includes for LogoClaim Backendlayout
[RM\RmBase\TypoScript\BackendlayoutCondition = pagets__pagelayout_logoclaim_portal] || [RM\RmBase\TypoScript\BackendlayoutCondition = pagets__pagelayout_logoclaim_subpage]
    page.includeJSFooter.belayoutJavascript = EXT:rm_base/Resources/Public/JS/be_logoclaim.js
[global]

## Custom JavaScript Includes for LogoFull Backendlayout
[RM\RmBase\TypoScript\BackendlayoutCondition = pagets__pagelayout_logofull_portal] || [RM\RmBase\TypoScript\BackendlayoutCondition = pagets__pagelayout_logofull_subpage]
    page.includeJSFooter.belayoutJavascript = EXT:rm_base/Resources/Public/JS/be_logofull.js
[global]
```

I get 8 Debugs from: `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($conditionParameters,'cond Params');`.

If I use it single:

```
## Custom JavaScript Includes for LogoClaim Backendlayout
[RM\RmBase\TypoScript\BackendlayoutCondition = pagets__pagelayout_logoclaim_portal]        
    page.includeJSFooter.belayoutJavascript = EXT:rm_base/Resources/Public/JS/be_logoclaim.js
[global]
[RM\RmBase\TypoScript\BackendlayoutCondition = pagets__pagelayout_logoclaim_subpage]
    page.includeJSFooter.belayoutJavascript = EXT:rm_base/Resources/Public/JS/be_logoclaim.js
[global]

## Custom JavaScript Includes for LogoFull Backendlayout
[RM\RmBase\TypoScript\BackendlayoutCondition = pagets__pagelayout_logofull_portal]        
    page.includeJSFooter.belayoutJavascript = EXT:rm_base/Resources/Public/JS/be_logofull.js
[global]
[RM\RmBase\TypoScript\BackendlayoutCondition = pagets__pagelayout_logofull_subpage]
    page.includeJSFooter.belayoutJavascript = EXT:rm_base/Resources/Public/JS/be_logofull.js
[global]
```

I get four debugs.

Logical the Condition is called 8 times in the OR-Variant and 4 times in the Single-Call-Variant.

---

My Idea was less redundant code, but it looks like a double-checking condition. So based on performance I better should use the Single-Call-Conditions?

What's the PROs and the CONs for this or that?

---

**Edit**

My Condition Code:

```
<?php
namespace RM\RmBase\TypoScript;

use \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Configuration\TypoScript\ConditionMatching\AbstractCondition;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;;

class BackendlayoutCondition extends AbstractCondition
{
    /**
     * Evaluate condition
     *
     * @param array $conditionParameters
     * @return bool
     */
    public function matchCondition(array $conditionParameters)
    {
        # Return false if in Backend (Condition for Frontend only)
        if (!$GLOBALS['TSFE']) return false;
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($conditionParameters,'cond Params');        
        # QueryBuilder for Table: pages
        $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('pages');

        # Check if current BackendLayout is inside the $conditionParameters
        if (!empty($conditionParameters) && substr($conditionParameters[0], 0, 1) === '=') {
            # Trim the Parameter to get the correct Value of the Parameter (behind '=')
            $conditionParameters[0] = trim(substr($conditionParameters[0], 1));

                # Get Backendlayout on this Page
                $backendLayoutOnThisPage = $queryBuilder
                    ->select('backend_layout')
                    ->from('pages')
                    ->where(
                        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('uid', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter(intval($GLOBALS['TSFE']->id), \PDO::PARAM_INT))
                    )
                    ->execute();

            # Store Backendlayout Value of the current Page in $backendLayoutOnThisPage
            $backendLayoutOnThisPage = $backendLayoutOnThisPage->fetch()['backend_layout'];
        } else {
            # If no ConditionParameter was set return false
            return false;
        }

        # Check if parent BackendLayout_NextLevel is inside the $conditionParameters
        if ($backendLayoutOnThisPage == '') {
            # Get pageRepository
            $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
            $pageRepository = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Page\\PageRepository');

            # Get Rootline of the current Page
            $pageRootline = $pageRepository->getRootLine(intval($GLOBALS['TSFE']->id));

            # Set rootlineIndex to the Parent Page Index
            $rootlineIndex = count($pageRootline)-2;

            # Check Parent Page Backendlayout_NextLevel till 0 or Backendlayout found
            while ($rootlineIndex > 0) {
                if ($pageRootline[$rootlineIndex]['backend_layout_next_level'] == $conditionParameters[0]) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    $rootlineIndex--;
                }
            }

            # No BackendLayout_NextLevel found till 0
            return false;
        } else {
            # If Condition Backendlayout found return true, otherwise return false
            if ($backendLayoutOnThisPage == $conditionParameters[0]) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please paste your condition class code here?

Comment: Question edited... Condition added ;)